# how to use the eval command in order to print the value of parameter

Tags: bash, shell-script

Please advice how to use the eval command in order to print the parameter value

for example

### bash

```
a=1
b=2
c=3


for i in ` echo a b c `
> do
> echo "$i=` eval $i ` "
> done

bash: a: command not found
a= 
bash: b: command not found
b= 
bash: c: command not found
c=
```

why I don’t get the requested output (from `for` loop command)

```
 a=1
 b=2
 c=3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `eval` in this instance

`eval $i` forces `eval` to evaluate the contents of `i` as a command - this is why you see errors such as `b: command not found` being reported

A better way would be to print parameter values with bash using [variable deferencing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-dereference-variable-names-inside-bash-functions)

```
for i in a b c; do echo "$i=${!i}"; done
a=1
b=2
c=3
```